# VPN Tunnel set up Issues - Cisco WRVS 4400N to Server 2008 R2behind ASA5505

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, cisco-vpn

I was wondering if someone could help with a scenario i have that i am not sure how to set up regarding a VPN tunnel set up.

I have a Cisco WRVS4400N business router , and on this device , i need to be able to set up a constantly running VPN connection to a Server2008 R2 machine running behind the Cisco ASA5505 firewall.

I have already opened the firewall on port 1723 to allow the VPN connection to pass through and i have tested this connection using telnet and it connects successfully.

The config is as follows:
Cisco 4400N firewall - IP address 192.168.5.1
The external IP address of my Server 2008 R2 VM is 81.x.x.x
The internal IP address of my server 2008 R2 VM is 172.16.0.121

Basically , I need to set up a tunnel on the Cisco 4400N router to connect to my Server 2008R2 VM behind my firewall .

I am able to create a Windows VPN connection directly from outside the firewall and get it to connect successfully to the Server 2008R2 Server but I am unable to set up the VPN tunnel on the Cisco router.

Is this even possible and also I think that the Cisco ASA5505 wont even come into the configuration , as the VPN is simply passing through this device.

Can anyone help me with this , as I am pulling my hair out?

Thanks

Matthew Lowe

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

I actually used to support these routers a few years ago working for Cisco. Your main problem lies in that the WRVS4400N only supports site to site IPSEC tunnels. Windows VPN and port 1723 is PPTP, which is completely different. WRVS4400N and other small business class routers (specifically the rebranded Linksys routers) only support client-to-site PPTP if they support PPTP at all.

**Solution**

The ONLY way to connect that server to the WRVS4400N via PPTP is if you were to set up the WRVS4400N as a PPTP server (may or may not be possible, I can not remember if that model will act as a PPTP server) and then connect the server acting as a PPTP Client to the WRVS4400N.